# Can client id and client secret be re-entered to use Coursera's OAuth2 api after one wrong entry?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I was testing accessing Coursera's CoAuth2 API. When I typed in courseraoauth2client config authorize --app APP it prompted me with client id, client secret and scope. However, as I was only testing I entered incorrect information. However, when I tried entering the correct information, by typing in

```
courseraoauth2client config authorize --app APP
```

it automatically opens the URL in my browser with the message

```
{"msg":"bad scopes string."}
```

without asking me for the client id, client secret and scope.

How do I fix this? Please help.

```
ourseraoauth2client config check-auth --app APP
INFO:root:Attempting to retrieve new tokens from the endpoint. You will be prompted to authorize yourapp in your web browser.
INFO:root:About to request new OAuth2 tokens from Coursera.
Please visit the following URL to authorize this app:
    https://accounts.coursera.org/oauth2/v1/auth?access_type=offline&state=44cfbef6f1344e80afc4a727e067711c&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fcallback&response_type=code&client_id=juhsts&scope=view_profile+%22tttests%22

Mac OS X detected; attempting to auto-open the url in your default browser...
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late to respond to this, but for anyone else who runs into this problem you can clear the info in your `<home directory>/.coursera/courseraoauth2client.cfg` file.

(It should be fine to delete everything in the file, as it will be re-filled as you authenticate a new app). This will allow you to start fresh at re-authenticating your app.

Alternatively, you can try re-authenticating the app under a new app name.

Edit: the scopes string should be formatted as: `scope1 scope2`, not encapsulated in quotes and only separated by white space.